# Session State ArrayList in Shopping Cart ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I'm creating a shopping cart application and I'm having some issues with implementing a session state for my arraylist.

in my page load i declared

```
 if (Session["Cart"] == null)
        {
            Session["Cart"] = new ArrayList();
        }

        else
        { 
            ArrayList cart = (ArrayList)Session["Cart"];
        }
```

to create the session if it doesn't exist yet. 
then i have an event handler for a button to add items to the arraylist

```
protected void onClick_AddBooking(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ClassID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString.Get("Class_Id"));
        ArrayList cart1 = new ArrayList();

        cart1 = Session["Cart"];       

        cart1.Add(ClassID);
```

i'm guessing i just don't know how to handle session states yet, thus the confusion. 
I'm essentially storing the class_ID then when the student confirms i'll store that to the DB and associate that ID with the Class Details.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: -1 - What is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a problem you are having?  Try the following:

```
protected void onClick_AddBooking(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ClassID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString.Get("Class_Id"));
        ArrayList cart1 = new ArrayList();

        cart1 = (ArrayList)Session["Cart"];       

        cart1.Add(ClassID);

        Session["Cart"] = cart1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a class where you define the properties `productName`, `productQty`, `productPrice`
then make the object of that class and add the values in these properties.
Then add that object into the `ArrayList` and save that `ArrayList` again in the session.